# El programa ha finalizado: código de salida: 3221225477

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa simple donde a una función me pasan como parámetro una `list<int>` y un `int` *m*, donde tengo que sacar el módulo de cada elemento de la lista, haciendo uso de *m*, para luego ubicarlos en un `vector<list<int>>`. Cada sublista está formada por el módulo obtenido, es decir, si me dan como `m = 2`, el vector va a tener dos posiciones siendo estas `[0]` y `[1]`.

```
void split_mod(list<int>&L, int m,vector<list<int>>&VL) {
  int Modaux=0;
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++) { 
    list<int>::iterator aux = L.begin();
    list<int>Laux;
    while(aux != L.end()){
        Modaux = *aux / m;
        if( Modaux == i){
            Laux.push_back(*aux);
        }
        aux++;
    }  
    VL[i] = Laux;
  }
}
```

Escribí eso como intento para solucionarlo, pero al correr el programa, crashea apareciendo el siguiente error:

> << El programa ha finalizado: codigo de salida: 3221225477 >>

Comment: Si bien tu pregunta está bien redactada, como guía, podrías revisar [estas preguntas en el sitio](/search?q=3221225477+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D).

Comment: ¿ El argumento `VL` tiene ya el tamaño adecuado, o lo recibes vacío y tienes que rellenarlo ?

Comment: El argumento VL no tiene tamaño, hay que rellenarlo

Comment: Ese era el error, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, escribe una auto-respuesta. Puede ser útil a futuros usuarios que tengan tu mismo problema, y colaboras al sitio.

Comment: No olvides que siempre puedes debugear el programa para encontrar el problema